# Querying a MySQL BINARY(8) column, using a std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11

I am currently teaching myself C++ (c++0x) so my apologies for any idiocy in this question.

I have an std::vector of length 8 that I want to query in a database to see if it is listed, and if not I will insert it into the database. It's an unsigned char as that is what the base64_decode implementation I have found returns.

This is my query & insert method as it currently stands:

```
int MySQLConnection::insertByteHash(std::vector<unsigned char> hashSection) {
    sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT byteHash_id FROM byteHash WHERE byteHash_content = ? LIMIT 1;");
    prep_stmt->setBlob(1, &hashSection);
    res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
    if(res->next()){
        return res->getInt("byteHash_id");
    }

    /*
    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO byteHash SET byteHash_content = ?;");
    prep_stmt->setBlob(1, &str);
    res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
    */

    return 1;
}
```

This is the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `byteHash` (
  `byteHash_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `byteHash_content` binary(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`byteHash_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_byteHash_content` (`byteHash_content`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

The binary data as hex is 8FDA7E1F0B56593F.

I was looking into strstream, but keep reading about it being depreciated (not that I managed to get it working anyway), so I am presuming there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The official standard is [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), C++0x was just the working name.

Comment: Also I'm confused. How is using `BINARY(8)` any better than `UNSIGNED BIGINT`?

Comment: @tadman; my apologies "c++0x" is the compiler flag I have been using. BINARY(8) won't have any benefit over unsigned bigint that I know of, but this is just me tinkering; the question could be rephrased as "how do I get binary data in and out of a mysql database from a std::vector<unsigned char>" but I wanted to give the explicit example that I am working with.

Comment: Not a big nag over the 0x thing, I just tagged it accordingly so people know what sort of answers to give. `BINARY` columns are sort of annoying to work with, so if it's just a 64-bit value, why not use `BIGINT` and convert your `vector` to a 64-bit unsigned?

Comment: Smashing plan; I'll give that a stab.